# Add linker flag in CMake and execute automatically a gcc command

Tags: c++, c, cmake, linker, clion

Maybe this thread could be similar to others but I need some help because I'm a CMAKE noob.
I need to let the following command execute automatically in my IDE (Clion).

`g++ main.cpp -L dependences/lib -lpq -o main`

As you can imagine, I have `libpq.dll` and `libpq.lib` in a directory called "dependences" inside my project.

My CMakeList at the moment is like this:

```sh
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(AccessoDB)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(AccessoDB main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(AccessoDB pq)
```

But I don't know how to get the library in that directory, and how to add the command at the beginning.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CMake link to external library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774593/cmake-link-to-external-library) The ways to link to an external library in CMake are listed in these answers, in particular, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10550334/3987854) one is likely the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes `main.cpp`, `CMakeLists.txt` and `dependencies` are in the same directory.

All parts of the command line parameters but `-L dependencies/lib` and `-o main` are already covered by the `CMakeLists.txt` file.

You could use the `link_directories` command to specify additional link directories, but personally I prefer using a imported library.

```
add_library(pq SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(pq PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/lib/libpq.dll"
    IMPORTED_IMPLIB "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/lib/libpq.lib")
```

`-o main` can be replaced by changing the `OUTPUT_NAME` (or `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_NAME`) target property. Note that this won't get rid of the extension; In this case you'll end up with `main.exe`. (You could change that using the `SUFFIX` target property, if required.)

```
set_target_properties(AccessoDB PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME main)
```

---

The resulting cmake file should look like this.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(AccessoDB)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(AccessoDB main.cpp)
set_target_properties(AccessoDB PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME main)

# define the properties of pq library
add_library(pq SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(pq PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/lib/libpq.dll"
    IMPORTED_IMPLIB "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/lib/libpq.lib")

#include directories could be added too
# target_include_directories(pq INTERFACE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/include/pq")


target_link_libraries(AccessoDB pq)
```

Note that there may still be problems when running the exe, since the `.dll` is probably not in a directory listed in the `PATH` environment variable and does not recide in the working directory when running the exe.